# Typegoose Ref returns null on parent object despite assigning a parent in child

Tags: mongoose, apollo-server, typegraphql, typegoose

I' trying to set up a simple example [from typegoose documentation](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/virtuals/#virtual-populate) with TypeGraphQl

Here are my types for child:

```
export enum Behavior {
  A = "good kitten",
  B = "very good kitten",
  C = "naughty kitten",
}

@ObjectType()
export class Kitten {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  readonly _id: string;

  @Field((type) => String)
  @prop({ required: false })
  parent: Ref<Person>;

  @Field((type) => String)
  @prop({ type: () => String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Field((type) => String)
  @prop({
    type: () => String,
    required: true,
    enum: Behavior,
    default: Behavior.B,
  })
  behavior?: Behavior;
}
```

and parent:

```
@ObjectType()
export class Person {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  readonly _id: string;

  @Field((type) => String)
  @prop({ type: () => String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Field((type) => [Kitten], { nullable: true })
  @prop({
    ref: () => Kitten,
    localField: () => "_id",
    foreignField: () => "parent",
  })
  pet?: Ref<Kitten>[];
}
```

Input Types:

```
@InputType()
export class NewKitten {
  @Field((type) => String)
  parent: Ref<Person>;

  @Field((type) => String)
  name: string;

  @Field((type) => String, { defaultValue: Behavior.B })
  behavior: Behavior;
}


@InputType()
export class NewPerson {
  @Field((type) => String)
  name: string;

  @Field((type) => [NewKitten], { nullable: true })
  pet?: Ref<NewKitten>[];
}
```

central processing file for models:

```
import { Person } from "../types/person.type";
import { Kitten } from "../types/kitten.type";
import { getModelForClass } from "@typegoose/typegoose";

export const PersonModel = getModelForClass(Person);
export const KittenModel = getModelForClass(Kitten);
```

and Resolvers:

```
@Resolver()
export class KittenResolver {
  @Query((returns) => [Kitten])
  async kittens(): Promise<Kitten[]> {
    return await KittenModel.find();
  }

  @Mutation((returns) => Kitten)
  async addKitten(@Arg("addKitten") addKitten: NewKitten): Promise<Kitten> {
    return await KittenModel.create(addKitten);
  }
}

@Resolver()
export class PersonResolver {
  @Query((returns) => [Person])
  async people(): Promise<Person[]> {
    return await PersonModel.find();
  }

  @Mutation((returns) => Person)
  async addPerson(@Arg("addPerson") addPerson: NewPerson): Promise<Person> {
    return await PersonModel.create(addPerson);
  }
}
```

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ref-typegoose-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^9.11.0",
    "apollo-server": "^3.10.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/config": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

In apollo studio i tried this out, but it doesn't work how i was expecting it.
Here i can create Person and then Kitten and assign it to Person, like so:

[image: add person mutation]
[image: add kitten mutation]

kitten query:

[image: kitten query]

but person's pet query still null:

[image: person query]

I was expecting a person's pet query to be filled with a new pet, but it didn't work. Is there a mistake in my code or did i misunderstood the functionality of typegoose reference entirely and it's not how it works?

Answer (score 0):

(This Question was also asked in [Github Discussions](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/discussions/753) with slightly different code and answered there)

The code in this Questions is missing `.populate`, which means that the virtuals were never actually populated. And after that it would turn out that virtuals would not be included in the output because `virtuals: true` was not set (see [Why is my virtual not included in the output?](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/virtuals#why-is-my-virtual-not-included-in-the-output)).

Also somehow all the above did not change the GraphQL output, but using `mongoose-autopopulate` did.

Note: I dont know much about GraphQL